# How to run Larvel's php artisan commands on Google App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have my staging site for a Laravel app hosted on a Google App Engine instance. The production site is hosted on Compute Engine and isn't a managed server so I am not as familiar with the set up on GAE - I wanted to try it out in order to eventually move our production site onto a managed server.

I'm having an issue where I can't figure out how to run `php artisan` commands on staging! I managed to use the google sdk and the cloud sql proxy in order to access the staging database, and I assumed I could use some kind of `gcloud` command to run the artisan command, like something like `gcloud --compute="php artisan migrate"` but I can't figure out the best way to do it.

I also have tried using GCP's in-app terminal to ssh into the instance, but it seems like I have no access to the actual project files within that ssh so I can't run the artisan commands.

Does anyone know best practices for running a migration on this type of server?

I'm also using an app.yaml file to build the instance, so I was thinking maybe I should figure out how to put the command there, but I'm not sure if that's the right move as the only information I have in that file is the env info and server resources info.

Please help! thank you :)

Comment: Glancing over https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible it seems you might be able to include the migration in the post-install scripts of the composer.json .

Comment: One way of running migrations to the laravel project that is hosted on GAE would be to connect your local environment project with the project's Google Cloud SQL, then running the migrations from your local environment.

Comment: @TMK Yes that was the solution thank you! if you post it as an answer to the question I can mark you as the correct answer

Comment: @movac Posted the comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of running migrations to your laravel project that is hosted on Google App Engine would be to connect your local environment project to the project's Google Cloud SQL. From there you can just run the migrations from your local environment.

Comment: For future people that get stuck: Download google cloud sdk, download google cloud sql proxy, connect via proxy to your server's DB as described in GCProxy documentation, change your .env (or whatever) so your project connects to the proxy DB and not your local DB, run migrations locally and it will update the proxy DB.

Answer (score 0):

Like @TMK said, connect through the SQL proxy. It's simple.

- Create an SQL instance using the instructions found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance)
- Follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible#set_up_database_sessions)

with that done, you can run your migration command right from your bash terminal